# Can a kernel preemption happen in the process context with `TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE` state?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

If a process sets itself to the sate of `TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE`, can it be preempted by other kernel components? If it does, I think this process maybe lost wake-up chance due to failed to check the wake-up condition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE` state has to do with the manner in which a task is put to sleep when it invokes the scheduler: its name is short for "interruptible sleep". It does not control preemption (and in fact Linux had `TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE` long before it was made (optionally) preemptible).

Preemption is not sleep; an executing task kicked off its CPU is runnable, not sleeping.

There would be total chaos if a task could be put to sleep if preempted while its sleep state is set to `TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE` or another sleep type.

Someone back in 2003 suspected the same thing as what I think you're suspecting and posted on the LKML mailing list:

http://lkml.org/lkml/2003/4/14/262

See Kernel developer Rob Love's followup and remaining discussion.

A `TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE` task must remain on the run queue under preemption. The hacks which make that happen, as they existed in 2003, are discussed in the above thread.

Comment: For example, when we want to put a process into sleep, we can do this: `prepare_to_wait(&q, &e, TASK_INTERRUPT); if(condition) schedule();` The `prepare_to_wait()` function will set the current process' state to `TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE` and then put it in the wait queue. What will happen if this process is preempted just after `prepare_to_wait()` and before `if()`? If the process definitely can be preempted here, and the condition has became true just before `prepare_to_wait()`, will it lost the only wake-up chance due to the fact that scheduler won't pich up any process with `TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE`.

Comment: A process need not be preempted for the condition to become true. Another *processor/core* can make it true.   The other  context which makes it true will and change this task's state to TASK_RUNNABLE. This is all properly interlocked through the queue structure.

Comment: I don't mean that a process need be preempted, however, it is preempted reluctantly. 1. the event this process is waiting is arrived. 2. process un-recognise it and puts itself into sleep. 3. just before it checks the event again, it is un-voluntarily preempted. 4. scheduler picks the next process from run-queue. 5. The process waiting event will never be waken up. I don't very clear that can this scenario happen?

Comment: The process isn't sleeping in the scenario that you describe. It is preempted. That means it is in a runnable state, but doesn't have the processor.  Since it isn't sleeping, it doesn't need to wake up. When a process in a runnable state begins executing on a processor once again, that is called a *dispatch* . Dispatches are not always from a sleeping state.

Comment: In the step 2 of which I described in the 3rd comment above -- `2. process un-recognise it and puts itself into sleep. `, if the process finishes executing `prepare_to_wait()` which set the state to `TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE`, and then it is preempted. Can it be waken up later? In this scenario, process is preempted when it is not in the run-queue.

Comment: The process is in the run_queue until it calls into the `schedule` function and perhaps even then (if `schedule` notices that the task is not in a sleep state).  Merely changing state to `TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE` and being preempted doesn't cause a task to sleep. Wait, I said that already --- in the answer!

Comment: I think I misunderstood your answers before. Now I'm clear. Thanks for your patience.